# Transition animation on page switch CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, css

I thought of a cool thing to do with my new site which is having a sliding transition between my pages. I have googled around and have found solutions like angular.js and many other like it, however those solutions seems to only work for single page use. Since I have more I would like to know if ther are any good and smooth ways of implementing an animation on the transition between two pages?

So basically, the current page should have an animation which moves the page to left or right depending on where the next page is in the horizontal menu while loading next page. When the target page has finished loading it will display an animation for that page sliding in from the opposite direction where to previous page dissappeared to.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over all the links in the page, instead of using hard coded links, delegate the navigation to a click event. In the event then you'd first play a slide-out animation before actually navigating to the target page.

You can pass the direction of entry animation as a parameter to the target page url. The target page should have its content out of view by default, then based on the animation direction parameter, you slide the content back in after page has loaded.

Comment: Word of warning though. The user experience for this won't be too nice. Page loading between the transitions can make the process rather sluggish. Loading new content via ajax and swap in the content will provide a more smooth experience.

Comment: I really like the idea of loading the site using AJAX as soon as the navigation is clicked, then running the animation for loading the screen when next page has loaded in AJAx and then display it. The purpose should be to make the small waiting time between navigating 2 pages a better experience using nifty and smooth page animations!

Comment: Well, there are people who thought of adding these kind of transitions to sites that's not built as single page app. I just saw this project, and it might be helpful if you haven't tried other solutions yet. http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/index.html